# WP Mail SMTP Plugin issue with sending mails

Tags: wordpress, smtp, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

we have a problem with WP Mail SMTP not being able to send mails.

Environment setup:

- We are running on PHP 7.3
- Our WordPress instance is actually an Amazon BeansTalk application with load balancer architecture that runs on Amazon Linux 2
- SMTP Service : We are using Google SMTP
- SMTP Plugin : WP Mail SMTP

Debug when sending a mail via the test mail function of the plugin :

```
Versions:
WordPress: 5.4.1
WordPress MS: No
PHP: 7.3.16
WP Mail SMTP: 2.1.1

Params:
Mailer: gmail
Constants: No
Client ID/Secret: Yes
Auth Code: Yes
Access Token: Yes

Server:
OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.0.2k 26 Jan 2017
PHP.allow_url_fopen: Yes
PHP.stream_socket_client(): Yes
PHP.fsockopen(): Yes
PHP.curl_version(): 7.61.1

PHPMailer Debug:
Invalid address: (setFrom) wordpress@
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `function.php`, Add your own code its easiest way. Use `wp_mail()` function.